# Output _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks() to a String

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, memory, memory-leaks

Is it possible to output the contents of the memory leak dump to a String (not a console)? Hopefully yes :)

```
_CrtDumpMemoryLeaks(); // to-string?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. But you can have _CrtDumpMemoryLeaks output to a file (using _CrtSetReportMode and _CrtSetReportFile) and then read that file into a string.